# Why FontWeights.Regular displays the same as FontWeights.Normal?

Tags: wpf

Has anyone else seen this? Is this a known bug and is there a fix for it?

Just create an empty `Window` and paste this inside:

```
<ComboBox Width="200">
  <x:Static Member="FontWeights.Normal"/>
  <x:Static Member="FontWeights.Regular"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Run it or just check in the designer (by placing cursor inside any of the two items). ComboBox displays both items as `Normal`. I checked `FontWeights` class too; there is no extra attribute or anything on any of the two static members. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have equivalent values as seen by the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/FontWeights.cs,45)

More specifically when [FontWeightToString](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/FontWeights.cs,216) is called (during [ToString()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/FontWeight.cs,199)), it is returning "Normal" for both FontWeights.

Comment: Hmm... I should have looked into that. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontweights.regular(v=vs.110).aspx in the Remarks section:

"Regular is equivalent in font weight to Normal."

The class definition probably also makes things a bit clearer too: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Core/System/Windows/FontWeights@cs/1/FontWeights@cs